# Concat python dataframes based on unique rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My dataframe reads like :

df1

```
user_id    username firstname lastname 
 123         abc      abc       abc
 456         def      def       def 
 789         ghi      ghi       ghi
```

df2

```
user_id     username  firstname lastname
 111         xyz       xyz       xyz
 456         def       def       def
 234         mnp       mnp        mnp
```

Now I want a output dataframe like

```
 user_id    username firstname lastname 
 123         abc      abc       abc
 456         def      def       def 
 789         ghi      ghi       ghi
 111         xyz       xyz       xyz
 234         mnp       mnp        mnp
```

As user_id `456` is common across both the dataframes. I have tried groupby on user_id `groupby(['user_id'])` . But looks like groupby need to be followed by some `aggregation` which I don't want here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('user_id').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   user_id username firstname lastname
0      123      abc       abc      abc
1      456      def       def      def
2      789      ghi       ghi      ghi
3      111      xyz       xyz      xyz
4      234      mnp       mnp      mnp
```

Solution with `groupby` and aggregate `first` is slowier:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('user_id', as_index=False, sort=False).first()
print (df)
   user_id username firstname lastname
0      123      abc       abc      abc
1      456      def       def      def
2      789      ghi       ghi      ghi
3      111      xyz       xyz      xyz
4      234      mnp       mnp      mnp
```

EDIT:

Another solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2[~np.in1d(df2['user_id'], df1['user_id'])]], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   user_id username firstname lastname
0      123      abc       abc      abc
1      456      def       def      def
2      789      ghi       ghi      ghi
3      111      xyz       xyz      xyz
4      234      mnp       mnp      mnp
```

Comment: Is it the best optimized way to do this. As I will be dealing with huge dataset. Just a query.

Comment: I think yes, `drop_duplicates` is faster as `groupby`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach with masking -

```
def app1(df1,df2):
    df20 = df2[~df2.user_id.isin(df1.user_id)]
    return pd.concat([df1, df20],axis=0)
```

Two more approaches using the underlying array data, `np.in1d`, `np.searchsorted` to get the mask of matches and then stacking those two and constructing an output dataframe from the stacked array data -

```
def app2(df1,df2):    
    df20_arr = df2.values[~np.in1d(df1.user_id.values, df2.user_id.values)]
    arr = np.vstack(( df1.values, df20_arr ))
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns= df1.columns)
    return df_out

def app3(df1,df2):
    a = df1.values
    b = df2.values

    df20_arr = b[~np.in1d(a[:,0], b[:,0])]
    arr = np.vstack(( a, df20_arr ))
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns= df1.columns)
    return df_out

def app4(df1,df2):
    a = df1.values
    b = df2.values

    b0 = b[:,0].astype(int)
    as0 = np.sort(a[:,0].astype(int))
    df20_arr = b[as0[np.searchsorted(as0,b0)] != b0]
    arr = np.vstack(( a, df20_arr ))
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns= df1.columns)
    return df_out
```

Timings for given sample -

```
In [49]: %timeit app1(df1,df2)
    ...: %timeit app2(df1,df2)
    ...: %timeit app3(df1,df2)
    ...: %timeit app4(df1,df2)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 753 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 192 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 181 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 171 µs per loop

# @jezrael's edited solution
In [85]: %timeit pd.concat([df1, df2[~np.in1d(df2['user_id'], df1['user_id'])]], ignore_index=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 614 µs per loop
```

Would be interesting to see how these fare on larger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use np.in1d to check for duplicate user_id.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2[df2.user_id.isin(np.setdiff1d(df2.user_id,df1.user_id))]])
```

Or to use a set to get unique rows from the merged records from df1 and df2. This one seems to be a few times faster.

```
pd.DataFrame(data=np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in np.r_[df1.values,df2.values]}),columns=df1.columns)
```

Timings:

```
%timeit pd.concat([df1,df2[df2.user_id.isin(np.setdiff1d(df2.user_id,df1.user_id))]])
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.48 ms per loop

%timeit pd.DataFrame(data=np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in np.r_[df1.values,df2.values]}),columns=df1.columns)

1000 loops, best of 3: 632 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `append` + `drop_duplicates`.

```
df1.append(df2)
df1.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```