# how do i join 2 dataframe with unique userID

Tags: python, dataframe, join, merge, anaconda

just started learning python on my own. so I have 2 dfs that look like this.

df1:

| userid | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 2 | b | 20 |
| 3 | c | 30 |
| 4 | d | 40 |
| 5 | e | 50 |

df2:

| userid | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | f | 60 |
| 7 | g | 70 |
| 8 | h | 80 |
| 4 | d | 40 |
| 2 | b | 20 |

As there are similar userIDs with name and count in both dfs, I was wondering how to join these two dataframes into df3 where it looks like this:

| userid | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 2 | b | 20 |
| 3 | c | 30 |
| 4 | d | 40 |
| 5 | e | 50 |
| 6 | f | 60 |
| 7 | g | 70 |
| 8 | h | 80 |

thank you

Comment: Your example would be more understood, if you use markdown for the sample data.

Comment: Yes Sir. I will try to change it to markdown now. sorry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using concat function.

```
# create an array of your dataframes
alldfs = [df1, df2]

# concat them
df3 = pd.concat(alldfs)
```

See documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-objects

Comment: wow it works... thank you very much for the answer and link. sorry for the trouble. i am still figuring out/searching for info on how to use mark down. thank you.

Comment: actually it didnt quite work... it should show 8 rows, instead of 10. :( but thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Here is another way (avoid dups): https://stackoverflow.com/a/61626765/2612429