# Merging or Join three DataFrames where all three DataFrames contain four identical columns and one unique column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have three DataFrames: DF1, DF2, DF3. They all contain the columns `['BHID','FROM','TO','SAMP ID','*unique element*']`. The DataFrames don't have the same amount of rows, but I would like to merge or join these DFs so that the final DataFrame contains all the *unique elements* where BHID FROM TO SAMP ID match exactly. The final DataFrame should look something like this -

```
BHID | FROM | TO | SAMP ID | *element 1* | *element2* | *element3*
```

I have tried the following approaches:

```
FinalDF = pd.merge(DF1,DF2,DF3, on=['BHID','FROM','TO','SAMP ID'], how='inner')
```

this gave me an error - `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Please can you assist with the right merging method or join method. It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat python dataframes based on unique rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236940/concat-python-dataframes-based-on-unique-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain `merge`:

```
cols = ['BHID','FROM','TO','SAMP ID']
out = DF1.merge(DF2, on=cols).merge(DF3, on=cols)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked well. It is a shame that you cant do this in one merge step...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` also :

```
out = pd.concat([DF1,DF2,DF3], axis = 0)[['BHID','FROM','TO','SAMP ID']]
```